# Paypal Json and Postal code is not Invalid

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I'm working on paypal payment method and its working fine but when i used a valid zip code, it shows me 400 error

```
[{"field":"city","issue":"Value is invalid"},{"field":"state","issue":"Value is invalid"},{"field":"zip","issue":"Value is invalid"}]
```

I have a link in which if user enters a wrong valid postal code then its proceed to paypal checkout page, but in my scenario its show an error message.

Secondly when i'm sending payer information like email, country code etc. then it shows that Invalid json. Here is my code.

```
$qty = Session::get('qty');
$TotalAmount = 0;
foreach (Session::get('cart') as $index => $product) {
$price = $product->product_price;
$TotalAmount = $TotalAmount + ($price * $qty[$index]);
$item[$index] = new Item();
$item[$index]->setName($product->product_title) /** item name **/
->setCurrency('USD')
->setQuantity($qty[$index])
->setPrice($price); /** unit price **/
}
// Billing Address
$billing_address = new ShippingAddress();
$billing_address->setLine1(''.$s_line1.'');
$billing_address->setCity(''.$s_city.'');
$billing_address->setState(''.$s_state.'');
$billing_address->setPostalCode(''.$s_postalcode.'');
$billing_address->setCountryCode(''.$s_country.'');
// Payer Information
$billing_info = new PayerInfo();
$billing_info->setFirstName(''.$s_first_name.'')->setLastName(''.$s_last_name.'')->setPhone(''.$s_phone.'')->setEmail(''.$s_company_name.'')->setCountryCode(''.$s_country.'');
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
$payer->setPayerInfo($billing_info);
//Create Item List Json
$item_list = new ItemList();
$item_list->setItems($item);
$item_list->setShippingAddress($billing_address);
// Create the WebProfile
$presentation = new Presentation();
$presentation->setLogoImage("https://example.com/uploads/header-logo.png")
->setBrandName("Machinery State! Paypal")
->setLocaleCode("US");
$inputFields = new InputFields();
$inputFields->setAllowNote(true)
->setNoShipping(1)
->setAddressOverride(0);
$webProfile = new WebProfile();
$webProfile->setName("ABC" . uniqid())
->setPresentation($presentation)
->setInputFields($inputFields);
$createdProfile = $webProfile->create($this->_api_context);
$createdProfileID = json_decode($createdProfile);
$profileid = $createdProfileID->id;
$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD')
->setTotal($TotalAmount);
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
->setItemList($item_list)
->setDescription('Your transaction description');
$redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(URL::route('status'))->setCancelUrl(URL::route('status'));
$payment = new Payment(); $payment->setIntent('Sale')
->setPayer($payer) ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
->setTransactions(array($transaction)) ->setExperienceProfileId($profileid);
try {
$payment->create($this->_api_context);
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($ex->getData())->withInput(Input::all());
}
```

**Note:**
All values are dynamic and comes from database.

Comment: Did you try asking this question to Paypal team first? Do you have any documentation that could help you with this?

Comment: What is `''.$s_first_name.''` supposed to do?

Comment: i forget to replace this its $s_first_name, nothing else

Comment: no i don't contact with paypal team

Comment: I just build using this by paypal documentation http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/